# Show $\int_{E_0}|f|<\epsilon$ and $|E_0|<\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I want to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $\delta >0$ such that $\int_{E_0}|f|<\epsilon$ or every measurable $E_0 \subset E$ such that $|E_0|<\delta$, where $E \subset \mathbb R^n$ and $f \in L(E)$ [$f$ is Lebesgue measurable].
We are given that $|f| = \lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} f_k$ on $E$ where each $f_k:E\rightarrow[0,\infty]$ is a simple and measurable function on E, and $f_k \leq f_{k+1}$ on $E$ for each $k\in N$

Here is what I have so far:

I know that 
$$\int _E |f| = \int _E\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} f_k$$
At this point we can use the monotone convergence theorem to say 
$$\int _E\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} f_k = \lim\limits_{k\rightarrow \infty} \int _E f_k$$
Now using the epsilon-delta definition of a limit we can say that 
$$\left|\int _E |f| - \int _E f_k \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$$
where $\epsilon > 0$. We can also bound the $f_k$ integral to be as small as we want, such as $\int _E f_k  < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Now we can say the following

$$\int _E |f| = \int _E |f| -f_k+f_k = \int _E \left(|f| -f_k \right) +\int _E f_k$$

We know that $\int _E |f| >0 $ so $\int _E |f| = \left| \int _E |f|\right|$ and 
$$\int _E |f| = \left| \int _E \left(|f| -f_k \right) +\int _E f_k \right|$$
using the triangle inequality yields
$$\left| \int _E \left(|f| -f_k \right) +\int _E f_k \right| \leq \left| \int _E \left(|f| -f_k \right) \right| +\left|\int _E f_k \right| $$
$$\leq \left| \int _E (|f| -f_k ) \right| +\int _E |f_k| = \left| \int _E (|f| -f_k ) \right| +\int _E f_k$$
We know that $\left|\int _E |f| - \int _E f_k \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\int _E f_k  < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ so we can say that 
$$\int _E |f| \leq \left| \int _E (|f| -f_k ) \right| +\int _E f_k < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$$
So we have $\int _E |f|  < \epsilon$, but since $E_0 \subset E$ this implies that $\int _{E_0} |f| \leq \int _E |f|  < \epsilon$

Now show that $|E_0|<\delta$. This is where I run into difficulty. I originally had this:
$$\int_{E_0} f_k = \sum\limits_{j=1}^m a_j |E_j|$$
where $a_j \in \mathbb R$ and $m \in N$. But we take the $\max(a_j)=A$ such that (**Note this is where the problem is**)
$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^m a_j |E_j| \leq \sum\limits_{j=1}^m A |E_j| = A \sum\limits_{j=1}^m  |E_j| = A |E_0| $$
We know that $f_k \leq |f|$ for all $k$ then $\int_{E_0} f_k \leq \int_{E_0} |f|$ which implies that $\int_{E_0} f_k < \epsilon$. So we get 
$$\int_{E_0} f_k \leq A |E_0| < \epsilon$$
Hence $|E_0| < \frac{\epsilon}{A} = \delta$. The problem is that when I take the max I introduce an inequality that messes $\int_{E_0} f_k < \epsilon$. Is there another way to approach this?